# How can i switch back from csm mode to uefi mode?

Tags: uefi

I just built my computer and I have accidentally switched it from uefi mode to csm mode. I still havent installed windows but im wondering if there is a way to convert it back to uefi?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not installed Windows, then you have nothing to do but go back into your BIOS and turn the CSM off. Note that *after* installing windows, it requires a reinstall to change modes.

If you're unable to get back into the BIOS for some reason, [see this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/665322/enabling-uefi-mode-in-bios-after-having-set-it-to-csm-mode-and-not-being-able-t?rq=1)