# How to boot from USB on ASUS X551CA?

Tags: boot, usb

This laptop - Asus X551CA, does not have any optical drive, and I am trying to boot it from USB, so I could install an OS to it, because its newly bought and has no OS in it.

My USB is perfectly bootable, but still, even on the BIOS setup, or when I press ESC at the system start, my USB does not appear as an option to boot from.

Can somebody help me out please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asus UEFI/BIOS options - How to boot from DVD?](http://superuser.com/questions/524598/asus-uefi-bios-options-how-to-boot-from-dvd)

Answer (score 12):

https://askubuntu.com/questions/237589/booting-ubuntu12-10-usb-on-asus-x401a-win8

That might be similar to your situation..

Under **Security** disable `Secure Boot Control`

Under **Boot** disable `Fast Boot`, then enable `Launch CSM`, then enable `Launch PXE OpROM`

Save changes and restart and press the `esc` key and choose boot from USB.

If that doesn't work...at least you have somewhere to start looking.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I can enable Launch PXE OpROM, but under Security the only options I see are under I/O Interface Security like LAN and CardReader Interface, Wireless Network Interface, USB Interface Security etc. I can not find the option Secure Boot Control.

Answer (score 6):

Plug in your USB boot device hold down <kbd>Esc</kbd> key it should come up with your USB boot device in the list, select it and off you go.

Good luck, just make sure secure boot is disabled in BIOS!

Answer (score 0):

To find the Secure Boot control you have to update the BIOS to the latest version
To do it, download the file and put it on your USB Root Directory
Next go into **BIOS** and then look for **Advanced\Easy Flash** And look for the update file in the root directory AKA F:0 or something.
Install it and stuff, then reboot into **BIOS** and try disabling secure boot again