# Booting from USB on Asus T100TA

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, bios, operating-systems, tablet

I have read that booting other operating systems via USB is theoretically possible on the Asus Transformer book, but I have not been able to get it to work. The main issue from booting on Windows 8.1 tablets is the secure boot mode that has to be turned off via restarting in UEFI mode, which I have done and double checked and triple checked. The USB is displayed as a UEFI bootable device, which is the only thing the T100TA can boot from, and when it is selected both from the boot menu and the BIOS setup the tablet screen simply 'refreshes' (flashes black for a fraction of a second and tears slightly) and shows no change in status. There is no option to disable fast boot in the boot menu, although I have done so through Windows 8.1's battery settings, I have not determined a way to switch to any CSM boot mode, and there is no setting for USB Legacy Mode. In the boot order list USB media has been set as first. I have made sure the operating systems I have tried to install are GPT formatted, but this has the same outcome, just the same as regular MBR and plain copying of ISO files directly to the USB. I have read multiple success stories with installation of alternate OS's on the T100TA, and followed instructions for doing so to the letter, but the process always grinds to a halt at the same place. Are there any suggestions for alternate ways of booting operating systems, or is there something else that I possibly haven't turned off/have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question too for ideas. [Asus UEFI/BIOS options - How to boot from DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/524598/asus-uefi-bios-options-how-to-boot-from-dvd)

But it could be, the thing you aren't mentioning, is the 32 or 64 bit of your setup.
e.g. The BIOS/UEFI is sometimes 32 or 64 bit only, so trying to boot the wrong version of the ISO will cause it to be ignored or fail.
So it matters what architecture is, not just the CPU itself, but the BIOS/UEFI, and then the media that is trying to be booted too.

At this low level of booting things, there, many things are hardcoded to be for specific architectures etc, that's why it's so sensitive to the right setup being in place.

Answer (score 0):

Your live media could be damaged, I'd recommend redownloading it, checking the hash, and flashing your disk again. Also, ensure the OS you are trying to boot is signed with a microsoft key, as some (such as PopOS) won't boot with Secure Boot.