# Install windows (no os preinstalled)

Tags: windows, uefi, asus-laptop

I bought an asus x554l with no os preinstalled. I am trying to install Windows 10 from usb but I can't find a way to access the bios and boot from usb. Any suggestions?

Comment: -1 Your question could more accurately be  "I can't find a way to access the bios and boot from usb"   And even then, you haven't listed what you tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I can't find a way to access the BIOS

For an Asus Notebook:

1. Press and hold the <kbd>F2</kbd> button, then click the power button.
2. Release the <kbd>F2</kbd> button, then you will see the BIOS screen.

   [image]

Source [How to enter the BIOS configuration of my Notebook?](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X555LI/0409_E9974_A.pdf)

---

#### How do I boot from a USB?

1. Before booting up the Notebook, insert the USB disk or the CD-ROM drive.
2. Enter the BIOS configuration of the system (see above)
3. Click "Boot" > enter the configuration of "Boot Option #1 " -> Select the proper device.

   For example, the picture below show how to set a USB disk as the first booting device.

   [image]

Source [How to boot the system from the USB disk or the CD-ROM drive?](https://www.asus.com/support/faq/1008277)

See also [Asus UEFI/BIOS options - How to boot from DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/524598/asus-uefi-bios-options-how-to-boot-from-dvd)

Comment: Nice answer. Would be even better if you add something about changing the boot device. For most of us this is obvious, but not everyone.

Comment: Is holding the function key down then releasing when the bios screen appears, equally effective as hammering away at it?  or is it the same as tapping it once?   Hammering seems like it might be advantageous sometimes but I have never heard of holding it down as being advantageous.

Comment: also, in your step 1, where you mention F2, you should be more clear that you're talking about his specific laptops(or whatever other laptops you are talking about), but that other laptops may use a different key.

Comment: Thanks. However in my case the screen was broken, that's why I was unable.